# How to use canvas.drawBitmap to display Bitmap randomly on screen

Tags: android, canvas, random, bitmap, render

(VERY new to Android)

I have a bitmap drawn onto a Canvas and I want to know how to make it display randomly each time the Activity is started and if it is possible to do this using `canvas.drawBitmap`?

I'm using SurfaceView and right now I have `canvas.drawBitmap` under a 
`public void render(Canvas canvas)` method. Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Random random = new Random();
canvas.drawBitmap(bitmap,random.nextInt(canvas.getWidth()-bitmap.getWidth()),random.nextInt(canvas.getHeight()-bitmap.getHeight()),null);
```

Comment: Alright thanks that makes sense! I was getting an error on nextInt: "The method nextInt(int) in the type Random is not applicable for the arguments (int, int)" But I deleted the 0 in nextInt and now it's displaying it randomly! However, it just keeps cycling through the random so the image is flashing all over the screen so I just need to figure out how to stop that.

Comment: yeah sorry im thinking javascript with (0,int) for random, use a boolean to control it in an if(){} block and after trigger the boolean so it will only go once, then you can retrigger it somewhere else